# how to make a Kaleidoscope in iPhone

Tags: iphone

i am trying to make a Kaleidoscope app in iPhone.
Some one can tell me how can make it, what kind of techs i must use, please !
thanks a lot for your helps, i am so worried now !

Thanks

Comment: Have you done any iPhone programming?  You might want to start with something simpler.

Answer (score 0):

To generate a random background and then do the two mirror reflections, you will need CoreGraphics/Quartz, and know about layers, and CGContexts.  In order to vary the background based on the movement of the iPhone, you need to learn how to read the accelerometer.

This is if you want to make it look similar to a real Kaleidoscope.  Otherwise you could take the much simpler approach of creating a graphic formulaicly based on random data that is then cropped to a pie slice and repeated twice to create a simple Kaleidoscope graphic.